# How do I connect to a wireless network?

Tags: 10.10, wireless

I just installed 10.10 x64 and cannot even find my wireless network let alone connect to it. I've searched all over SE and Ubuntu forums and cannot find out how to do this simple thing.

Can some one please give me the answer? It is plugged in right now and is 100% updated.

It is a Desktop with wireless card.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Here's the output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT2860
   vendor: RaLink
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 70:1a:04:f4:de:e9
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=2.6.35-27-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:fcff0000-fcffffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 03
   serial: 00:23:54:fd:c2:32
   size: 100MB/s
   capacity: 1GB/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100MB/s
   resources: irq:44 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fceff000-fcefffff memory:ddffc000-ddffffff memory:fcec0000-fcedffff
```

### Update

I have discovered that this is a know issue with the rt2860. I have been following step by step the instructions found [here](http://www.ctbarker.info/2010/05/ubuntu-1004-wireless-chipsets-and-wpa.html)

I decided to stat over because I was getting stuck on step 5:
`sudo rmmod rt2860sta`

is was giving me this problem:

`ERROR: Module rt2860sta does not exist in /proc/modules`

Since I started over I cannot even get past step 5
`sudo make`

I get this:
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

I am lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a notebook, right? Can you post the output of `rfkill list wifi`?

Comment: Can you post the wireless information part from `sudo lshw -c network`?

Comment: Have you checked if there are any restricted drivers available for your wlan card? Check System->Administration->"Additional Drivers"

Comment: Yes, I checked for additional drivers, and there was nothing.

Comment: When I add the output for `sudo lshw -c network`, it reads *-network DISABLED. How do I fix that?

Comment: Looks like this is a near impossible thing to fix. I'll just buy a new wireless card. Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone ever encounters the problem, here is what I did to fix this.
`sudo modprobe rt2860sta`

Needed to insert the module because Ubuntu cones with generic drivers. Run this code to verify:`locate rt2860sta.ko`

No need to download additional drivers.

There may need to be some minor tweaking, but I hope this helps anyone experiencing the same problem.